# How to make the section and aside touch the footer?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I got my footer to touch the bottom of the page all time by using the following css

```
 footer {
      width: 100%;
      bottom: 0;
      position: fixed;        
 }
```

Now I want to know how to make the section and aside touch the top of the footer at all times. I am using the following as style directives for the section and aside.

```
 section {
     float: left;
     background-color : red;
     width : 80%;

     }

aside{
      width : 20%;
      float : left;
      background-color : green;
    }
```

If I give height some particular pixel value it will not render correctly in some other screen size.
What should I use in addition so the height is responsive and covers the area from header to footer all the time in all the various sizes of screen, wherever the page is going to be rendered? Any hint which will help me come out of this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can either make a two column sticky footer using `display:flex` or `display:table`.  Have a search for it, there are plenty of examples out there

Comment: Do you want Section and Aside to scroll?

Comment: Scrolling is fine as long as the section  and aside content areas are covering the area from header to footer all the time.

Comment: What I mean is, is the application going to just be full-screen, or is it going to flow longer than the page height (scrolling needed)? Also does the footer height need to be dynamic or is it fixed?

Comment: The footer height need not be dynamic for sure, and the application in all probability will just be a full-screen one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ftxrfoya/2/

Comment: @Pete Doesn't need to be that complicated. Plus, he didn't specify a header :)

Comment: To be fair I don't really get flex, haven't used it much as we still have to support ie 8 so was just having a play with it but I would go the table route - allows for equal height columns and for the content to push the footer off the bottom of the page if the content is long enough (rather than going under the footer) http://jsfiddle.net/XGhP8/70/

Comment: Yes I did n't specify the header but in the question I have mentioned the header.And the page does contain the header. @Pete thanks for the effort.

Comment: @Pete The same reason I don't use flex. I haven't come across a problem that flex alone can solve. I'm not bothered about IE8 myself but it [doesn't work in IE9 and only partially in IE10](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Hopefully Windows 10 can help the journey to get rid of IE dependencies :/.

Comment: @JohnDoe - `dislpay:table` with header - http://jsfiddle.net/XGhP8/71/

Comment: Why are you wrapping everything in a wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are based upon the Aside being 20% width and the Footer being 20% height. You can adjust accordingly. For the scrolling one, just remove the height attributes to allow it to be dynamic, but I would put a `min-height:80%;` on them just in case :). You don't need any of these silly wrappers ;).

#### Non-Scrolling

`position:fixed;` all elements and lay them out using top, left, right and bottom percentages to suit.

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
footer {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top:80%;
    background-color:orange;
}
section {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:20%;
    right:0;
    bottom:20%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(254,252,234,1) 0%,rgba(241,218,54,1) 100%);
}
aside {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:80%;
    bottom:20%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(241,218,54,1) 0%,rgba(254,252,234,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<aside></aside>
<section></section>
<footer></footer>
```

#### Scrolling

Add `padding-bottom` to the aside and section of the same value as the height of the footer.

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
footer {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top:80%;
    background-color:orange;
}
section {
    float: left;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(254,252,234,1) 0%,rgba(241,218,54,1) 100%);
    width : 80%;
    height:100%;
    padding-bottom:20%;
}
aside {
    width : 20%;
    float : left;
    height:100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(241,218,54,1) 0%,rgba(254,252,234,1) 100%);
    padding-bottom:20%;
}
```

```html
<aside></aside>
<section></section>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest that you use a wrapper for your whole footer.

like this:

```css
//this is the fixed block
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.aside {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  width: 19%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="aside"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you are missing the point, OP wants the aside and section to be the same height and touch the footer (probably without using set heights in px) so your yellow block should be the same height as your blue block

Comment: Must admit @Pete got me correct, but  you are enclosing everything in a wrapper div. How it will benefit?